# How can I save my image as BMP format?

Tags: android, image, save, bmp

I know that I should use the compress method for saving a bitmap file.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagefile);

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

but I want to save my image as bmp format while "Bitmap.CompressFormat" only supports PNG and JPEG. How can I save my image file as BMP format?

Thanks,

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909429/android-save-a-bitmap-to-bmp-file-format

Answer (score 0):

you can use [copyPixelsToBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsToBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29)

to store the bitmap pixel into a buffer and, than wrote your buffer into the sd.

Comment: I did it but I did not get result:

`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagefile);

  ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);
   bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(bf);
  fos.write(bf.array());
   fos.flush();
  fos.close();
   return true;`

Comment: sorry I just misunderstood documentation. sorry