# How can I store captured image from camera with bmp filename extension

Tags: android, image

When I store captured image from camera after cropping, cropped jpg image file is

stored in my specified folder.

I want to store "that" cropped image file with bmp filename extension.

Comment: If a post solves your problem, Please mark it as answer, That's the way of showing courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the steps are:

1. After cropped jpg you convert it to Bitmap with this code

   ```
   Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
   ```
2. Save bMap with bmp extention you can follow suggest function over [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909429/android-save-a-bitmap-to-bmp-file-format)
3. Delete cropped jpg file to free memory

   ```
   File dir = getFilesDir();

   File file = new File(dir, "filename");

   if (file.exists()) {

    boolean deleted = file.delete();

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code -

```
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(AbsoluteFilePath);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

SOURCE : [Save bitmap to location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)